# Get live width of div as window resizes?

Tags: jquery, html, resize, window, width

Let's say I have a section, it's width is 1181 (as outputted in the console) and I am using the following code to find out the width of it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var body_size = jQuery('section').width();
    console.log(body_size);
});
```

If I re-size my browser, I have to reload the page to find out the new size of this div.

Is there a way to find out the size as I re-size my browser?

Comment: See the `resize` event - http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: `$(window).resize(fn)`..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle the "resize" event. Be warned that the event is fired *very* frequently, so it's a good idea to not do any DOM manipulation while in the handler, or as little as possible. One way to deal with the issue is to use a timer:

```
var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    var body_size = $('section').width();
    // ...
    // do your work here
    // ...
  }, 200);
});
```

That sets up a timer so that you won't actually do any work until at least 200 milliseconds after the user stops resizing (or pauses for a bit).

Comment: One quick question. How would I go about deleting the previous size and only show the new size?

Comment: @KeithDonegan that depends on how you're "showing" the size.  Are you updating some element on the page?  If you mean in the console, you can't; there's no console API to go back and change something that's already been logged.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just want to display it in another div. Something like: "Div is: 672px" etc

Comment: @KeithDonegan oh OK well for something that simple I'd use a `<span id=body_size>` or something and then just update it with `$('#body_size').text(body_size);` in the timeout handler.

Comment: Perfect again, I was use prepend! Thanks so much for your help Pointy.